# setOnClickListener on a view with drawable object

Tags: android, drawable, onclicklistener

Good day.

I have a LinearLayout bitmapBox in which I'm placing drawable object through a SandboxView class like this:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.bitmapBox);
View view = new SandboxView(this.getActivity(), bitmap);
myLayout.addView(view);
```

In the parent Layout I also have a horizontal scrollView, but I would like to make it visible/invisible by touching the canvas. I tried to do it in this way:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
int x = 0;

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
  HorizontalScrollView myLayout = (HorizontalScrollView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.hide);
  if (x == 0) {
    myLayout.setVisibility(1);
    myLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    x = 1;
  }

  else {
    myLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    x = 0;
  }
}
});
```

Is "view" not the object that holds the bitmap on canvas? Because this is not working. I don't know what view to use for setting up the onClick listener, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your onClickListener could be cleaned up a little:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // no need to cast to horizontalscrollview here since we are just setting visibility which is available to anything extending the View class.
        View mView = mRoot.findViewById(R.id.hide);
        if (mView == null) {
            return; // do nothing
        } else if (mView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (mView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the layout's clickable property to true.